# function overloading in c++ not working

Tags: c++

When I run this program it produce error `[Error] call of overloaded 'add(double, double, double)' is ambiguous`.

Why is that? I mean the function argument has different datatype which is infact function overloading, then why error?

However when the float is replaced by double, it works fine.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

    void add(){
       cout<<"I am parameterless and return nothing";
    }

    int add( int a, int b ){
        int z = a+b;
        return z;
    }

    int add(int a, int b, int c){
         int z = a+b+c;
         return z;
    }

   int add(float a, float b, float c)
    {
         int z = a +b + c;
         return z;
    }

int main()
{
   cout<<"The void add() function -> ";
   add();
   cout<<endl;
   cout<<"add(2,3) -> "<<add(2,3)<<endl;
   cout<<"add(2,3,4) -> "<<add(2,3,4)<<endl;
   cout<<"add(2.1,4.5) -> "<<add(2.8,3.1,4.1)<<endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because you call a function using ***`double`*** literal, and those can be converted to either `int` *or* to `float`, and the compiler don't know which it should pick.

The easiest solution is to call the function with `float` literals instead:

```
add(2.8f,3.1f,4.1f)
```